# Custom UIAlertView and Action sheet

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have found this wonderful free project (from [github](https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets)) to use for custom UIAlertView and action sheets. I was wondering if I end up using both these options, whether apple would reject my application? I have heard you cannot use private libraries. Does this classify as that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any libraries you want as long as the library has a license compatible with the App Store and as long as the library doesn't use any private APIs from Apple.

The library you ask about should be fine.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept in 6 minutes:) For future reference, how can I know if a library calls private APIs from Apple?

Comment: By looking at the source code. Or you can build your app, archive it, and validate it with the Organizer. If the library is used by an app in the App Store then you know it's OK.

Comment: Umm, I wouldn't assume that just because it has been approved once that it will be again....

Comment: @lnafziger No, it's not a guarantee of course but many of the popular libraries are pretty safe.

Comment: That I'll agree with!  :-)